# rtmp cdn to cloud streamer or free sreamer

Tags: http-live-streaming, rtmp, rtmps

I am new into RTMP and live streaming.

I have my rtmp server, but the issue is distribution, was looking for a simple rtpms streaming cdn. That can support audio streaming with HSL or dash support.

Or something free similar to youtube live, but for audio but with embeddable html.

Answer (score 0):

Recently(2022.01) most of CDNs support only file-based streaming protocol, like HLS/DASH/CMAF, even you publish the stream by RTMP or WebRTC, the CDN also covert the stream to these protocols.

If you want to build low lagging live streaming application, like RTMP, HTTP-FLV is recommend and you need a CDN to support HTTP-FLV rather than RTMP. HTTP-FLV works well on PC or mobile, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70429640/17679565).

You could build your CDN by open-source media-server cluster, like [SRS Edge](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/wiki/v4_EN_SampleRTMPCluster) to delivery HTTP-FLV, based on AWS EC2.

For CDN which support HTTP-FLV, you could check Tencent [Cloud Streaming Services](https://intl.cloud.tencent.com/products/css), which supports publish by RTMP, and deliver by HLS/HTTP-FLV/WebRTC.